# What is wrong with SupportMapFragment?

Tags: android, adt, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I have adt x86-64 mac os. I did everything from maps v2 documentation but i still get:

09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  ... 20 more
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.service.ro-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.service.ro-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
09-28 03:07:11.755: E/AndroidRuntime(549):  ... 23 more

My AndroidManifest look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.service.ro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.service.ro.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.service.ro.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="homeview.DetailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="homeview.Start"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="******************************" />




    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Google Play Services lib as dependency of your project?

Comment: yes i have it as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

Delete the android dependencies from java build path Libraries tab.
There should be only :

Android 4.xx
Android Private Libraries